# Is there a library for swift that lets you custom the order of the keys in a JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, encode, codable

I have the following situation:

```
struct RequestCommand: Codable {
    var event: String
    var uuid: String
    var type: String
    var data: [String]
}

var data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(RequestCommand(event: "click", uuid: "123456", type: "Button", data: ["A", "B", "C"]))

print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

The result of the print statement is the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "event": "click",
  "type": "Button",
  "uuid": "123456"
}
```

As you can see the order of the keys in the JSON isn't the same as the fields in the RequestCommand.
I know that JSONEncoder doesn't guarantee the order, also using .sortedKeys would not work for me since I must keep the exact order of the fields from the RequestCommand and I cannot rename them.
My question is, is there a library in swift that gives me the option of keeping the exact same order from the swift object in the JSON?

Comment: JSON is an **unordered collection** of zero or more name/value pairs.

Comment: Why do you need order? Since it shouldn't be important?

Comment: I send these json objects to the server and for them the order of the keys is important for deserialisation, I know this is not conforming with the JSON protocol but it is what it is and we cannot change it

Comment: @Claudiu why would it be important? Are they trying to access JSON values using index? You use keys to access values in JSON not index.

Comment: @KeshuR. from my understanding they are using some decoding based on a tree, each key is a node and if they decode a node before another then errors are thrown

Comment: `JSONEncoder` is able to encode the keys in lexicographic order but you cannot keep an arbitrary order. But the order doesn't matter on the server side as the dictionary values are retrieved by the keys (not by an index).

Comment: Instead of trying to achieve this illogical goal, you should immediately change your approach to your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

`for (key, value) in OrderedDictionary` will maintain the order.

```
struct OrderedDictionary<KeyType:Hashable, ValueType> {
    private var _dictionary:Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>
    private var _keys:Array<KeyType>

    init() {
        _dictionary = [:]
        _keys = []
    }

    init(minimumCapacity:Int) {
        _dictionary = Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>(minimumCapacity:minimumCapacity)
        _keys = Array<KeyType>()
    }

    init(_ dictionary:Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>) {
        _dictionary = dictionary
        _keys = map(dictionary.keys) { $0 }
    }

    subscript(key:KeyType) -> ValueType? {
        get {
            return _dictionary[key]
        }
        set {
            if newValue == nil {
                self.removeValueForKey(key)
            }
            else {
                self.updateValue(newValue!, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }

    mutating func updateValue(value:ValueType, forKey key:KeyType) -> ValueType? {
        let oldValue = _dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        if oldValue == nil {
            _keys.append(key)
        }
        return oldValue
    }

    mutating func removeValueForKey(key:KeyType) {
        _keys = _keys.filter { $0 != key }
        _dictionary.removeValueForKey(key)
    }

    mutating func removeAll(keepCapacity:Int) {
        _keys = []
        _dictionary = Dictionary<KeyType,ValueType>(minimumCapacity: keepCapacity)
    }

    var count: Int { get { return _dictionary.count } }

    // keys isn't lazy evaluated because it's just an array anyway
    var keys:[KeyType] { get { return _keys } }

    // values is lazy evaluated because of the dictionary lookup and creating a new array
    var values:GeneratorOf<ValueType> {
        get {
            var index = 0
            return GeneratorOf<ValueType> {
                if index >= self._keys.count {
                    return nil
                }
                else {
                    let key = self._keys[index]
                    index++
                    return self._dictionary[key]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension OrderedDictionary : SequenceType {
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<(KeyType, ValueType)> {
        var index = 0
        return GeneratorOf<(KeyType, ValueType)> {
            if index >= self._keys.count {
                return nil
            }
            else {
                let key = self._keys[index]
                index++
                return (key, self._dictionary[key]!)
            }
        }
    }
}

func ==<Key: Equatable, Value: Equatable>(lhs: OrderedDictionary<Key, Value>, rhs: OrderedDictionary<Key, Value>) -> Bool {
    return lhs._keys == rhs._keys && lhs._dictionary == rhs._dictionary
}

func !=<Key: Equatable, Value: Equatable>(lhs: OrderedDictionary<Key, Value>, rhs: OrderedDictionary<Key, Value>) -> Bool {
    return lhs._keys != rhs._keys || lhs._dictionary != rhs._dictionary
}
```

Comment: Does SwiftyJSON guarantee to keep the order?

Comment: Hey I have updated the answer. I got your question wrong. You can use above class for ordered insertion. Indeed SwiftufyJson does not guarantee the order.

Comment: I don't quite understand how should I apply this for my case, do you care to explain it in a little more detail